# How did Google configure Dynamic Views?

Tags: google, blogger

If you check the [official google blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com), you will find that it has an heavily modded version of Dynamic View, how did they manage to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to hack into the "Edit HTML option" inside Blogger and changing the various HTML code inside to fit your needs. I am afraid I could not find any easy way to copy their styling, but you can take a look at the original source code of the Google Blog to have an idea of where (and how) to start.

Comment: That's new, When i posted the question, the Edit HTML option was not there ! thanks !